# How to set limit $this->User->findByFirstName('Nadim');

Tags: php, cakephp

How to set limit to this query

```
$this->User->findByFirstName('Nadim',array('User.id','User.first_name','User.last_name'));
```

it sql is

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`first_name`, `User`.`last_name` FROM `users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`first_name` = 'Nadim' limit 1
```

I want to remove limit 1

Comment: If you want to remove `LIMIT 1` than remove it...

Comment: How can remove limit from findByFirstName. I am asking for cakephp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [findBy()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#findby) functions return results like `find('first')`, you cannot set limit to it, you need to use [findAllBy()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#findallby) instead.